# Firebase Send Verification Email doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was wondering if anybody else has the same problem, I'm working on a project using Firebase Email and Password for login, everything works fine except Verification Email, here's the code down there does anybody else has this problem? is it belong to Google? or it's something that I'm doing it wrong?
because the signUp method works fine and the user will be created after user press the Register button, but sendVerificationEmail method never been called

this is the signUp method which includes **sendVerificationEmail** method:

```
if (checkSignUpFormFields()) {
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "Your account successfully created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            sendVerificationEmail();
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "something went wrong, Check your information",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

and this is the method for sending verification method:

```
private void sendVerificationEmail(){
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null){
        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "Verification Email has been sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LaunchActivity.this, "Something went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So to clarify, if you put a breakpoint in sendVerificationEmail, the method is never called?

Comment: Let's start debugging of code.to check better where it was going?

Comment: @JenPerson yes i dont see it being called in debbuger panel

Comment: @JenPerson it was google issue, I'm receiving email one after another from the bunch of sign up I've done about an hour ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some issue with Firebase itself, I received an Email for a registration I've made about an hour ago, it's just taking so long more than an hour or so,  and must be **Googles** issue.